# Lambda layer: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a “Graph” tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a problem similar to this post: [Tensorflow 2.1.0 - An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551145/tensorflow-2-1-0-an-op-outside-of-the-function-building-code-is-being-passed-a)

My model includes a TimeDistributed wrapper around a CNN, whose input layer is first normalized by a lambda function:

```
    # ENCODER
    # video input
    frames = 10
    video_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(frames, 256, 256, 3))

    # cnn 1 frame input
    frame_in = Input(shape=(256,256,3), name='frame_input')
    #normalisation layer
    cnn = Lambda(lambda inputs: frame_in / 255)(frame_in)
    # add cnn layers + activations
    cnn = Conv2D(filters=num_filters[0], kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(4,4), padding='same', activation = 'relu', data_format='channels_last', name = 'Layer_1')(cnn) #input_shape=(64,64,3), data_format='channels_last'), name = 'Layer_1')(frame_in)
    cnn = Conv2D(filters=num_filters[1], kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(4,4), padding='same', activation = 'relu', name = 'Layer_2')(cnn)
    cnn = Conv2D(filters=num_filters[2], kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation = 'relu', name = 'Layer_3')(cnn)
    cnn = Conv2D(filters=num_filters[3], kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation = 'relu', name = 'Layer_4')(cnn)
    cnn = Conv2D(filters=num_filters[4], kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation = 'relu', name = 'Layer_5')(cnn)
    # flatten
    cnn = Flatten()(cnn)
    #time distributed
    time_dist_cnn = Model(inputs=frame_in, outputs=cnn, name='Time_Distributed_CNN')
    time_dist_0 = TimeDistributed(time_dist_cnn)(video_input)
```

The error is the same:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: frame_input:0
```

I know the problem is almost the same, and stems from the use of a lambda expression, but I'm not sure how to solve it in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running under eager mode, tensorflow operations will check if the inputs are of type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor` and keras ops are implemented as DAGs. So if the inputs to the eager mode is of `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`, then this throws the error.

You can change the input type to EagerTensor by explicity telling tensorflow to run in eager mode for keras by using `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)`. Adding this statement should solve your issue.

Alternatively, also disabling the eager execution by adding `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` at the top of the program will also runs the program successfully.

For example, this program throws the error you are facing -

**Code to reproduce the error-**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, models

def get_loss_fcn(w):
    def loss_fcn(y_true, y_pred):
        loss = w * losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
        return loss
    return loss_fcn

data_x = np.random.rand(5, 4, 1)
data_w = np.random.rand(5, 4)
data_y = np.random.rand(5, 4, 1)

x = layers.Input([4, 1])
w = layers.Input([4])
y = layers.Activation('tanh')(x)
model = models.Model(inputs=[x, w], outputs=y)
loss = get_loss_fcn(model.input[1])

model.compile(loss=loss)
model.fit((data_x, data_w), data_y)
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: input_8:0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

_SymbolicException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     72       raise core._SymbolicException(
     73           "Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic "
---> 74           "tensors, but found {}".format(keras_symbolic_tensors))
     75     raise e
     76   # pylint: enable=protected-access

_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'input_8:0' shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32>]
```

**Solution 1 -** Adding this `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` at the top of the program runs the program successfully. Also adding `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` at the top of the progrm to disable eager execution also runs the program successfully.

**Fixed code -**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, models

tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)

def get_loss_fcn(w):
    def loss_fcn(y_true, y_pred):
        loss = w * losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
        return loss
    return loss_fcn

data_x = np.random.rand(5, 4, 1)
data_w = np.random.rand(5, 4)
data_y = np.random.rand(5, 4, 1)

x = layers.Input([4, 1])
w = layers.Input([4])
y = layers.Activation('tanh')(x)
model = models.Model(inputs=[x, w], outputs=y)
loss = get_loss_fcn(model.input[1])

model.compile(loss=loss)
model.fit((data_x, data_w), data_y)

print('Done.')
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Done.
```

---

**Solution 2 -** Also kindly try the below solution, you can try modifying as below and see if works -

1) Create `normalize_input` function as follows:

```
def normalize_input(inputs):
    norm_input = inputs / 255
    return norm_input
```

2) Modify the `Lambda` layer as follows:

```
cnn = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(function=normalize_input)([frame_in])
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @DSPmagician - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: The problem as you may have guessed was simply the mistake in the lambda function, so solution 2 is correct. I modified it to `normed = Lambda(lambda x: x/ 255)(frame_in)`  and this worked fine. It would perhaps be good to put solution 2 on top of the answer since it was just a simple typo. Thank you kindly for the help.